# Brother printer

Tags: 14.04, printing, brother

I am trying to get a Brother MFC-J485DW printer to load to my laptop. I get a command to load `/usr/lib/cups/filter/brother_lpdwrapper_mfcj485dw`, but the command is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the correct drivers and everything install for your printer?

You can install the driver from [Brother](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj485dw_us_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006646_000&flang=4&type3=565) or by install the [.deb](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj485dw_us_as&os=128&dlid=dlf102098_000&flang=4&type3=559)

You also need the [CUPSwrapper](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj485dw_us_as&os=128&dlid=dlf102099_000&flang=4&type3=561)

To set up the printer after installing the correct drivers go to

```
settings -> additional drivers
```

If you need to set-up a scanner you can install the correct [32bit .deb](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj485dw_us_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006646_000&flang=4&type3=565) or [64bit .deb](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj485dw_us_as&os=128&dlid=dlf006645_000&flang=4&type3=566)

You can look here for the [download list.](https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfcj485dw_us_as&os=128)